# Unable to get the required data from xml to csv using xslt

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt

I am trying to load the data from XML to csv, but some of the nodes data I am missing.
Below is my Java code,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;


public class XML2CSV {

public static int transform(InputStream is, OutputStream os, Transformer transformer, QName name) throws XMLStreamException, TransformerException {
    long time1 = System.nanoTime();
    // Open input & output files
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, true);
    factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_VALIDATING, false);
    XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(is);
    // In case you want to check which implementation is used.
    // Woodstox is a bit faster, but not worth adding extra dependency.
    Result result = new StreamResult(os);
    transformer.transform(new StAXSource(reader), result);

    int count = 0;
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        if (reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT && name.equals(reader.getName())) {
            // System.out.println("FOUND " + count);
            count++;

            if (count % 1000 == 0) {
                long time2 = System.nanoTime();
                double ms = (time2 - time1) / 1000000.0;
                System.out.format("Time=%.2fms Rows=%d%n", ms, count);
            }
        } else if (reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {
//                    System.out.println("Start "+reader.getName()+" != "+name);
        }
        reader.next();
    }
    long time2 = System.nanoTime();
    double ms = (time2 - time1) / 1000000.0;
    System.out.format("Total Time=%.2fms Total rows=%d%n", ms, count);
    return count;
}

public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
    // Parse command line options
    File xsltFile;
    File inputFile;
    File outputFile;
    String tagName;
    String namespace;
    try {
        String xsltFileName = parse("-x", arg, "XSLT sheet", true);
        String inputFileName = parse("-f", arg, "Input file", true);
        String outputFileName = parse("-o", arg, "Output file", true);
        tagName = parse("-t", arg, "Tag name", true);
        namespace = parse("-n", arg, "Tag Namespace URL", false);
        xsltFile = new File(xsltFileName);
        inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
        outputFile = new File(outputFileName);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.err.println("Syntax: XML2CSV -f <input file> -o <output file> -x <XSLT stylesheet> -t <Tag name> [-n <namespace URL>]");
        System.err.println("Will split given file on given tag with given namespace.");
        System.err.println("Will process contents of each tag using given XSLT.");
        System.exit(1);
        return;
    }
    if (!xsltFile.exists()) {
        System.err.println("File not found " + xsltFile.getAbsolutePath());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    if (!inputFile.exists()) {
        System.err.println("File not found " + inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Open XSLT stylesheet
    StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(xsltFile);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);

    // Create XML tag name which is used to break up XML into rows
    final QName name;
    if (namespace != null) {
        name = new QName(namespace, tagName);
    } else {
        name = new QName(tagName);
    }
    System.out.println("Will look for tag " + name + " in namespace " + namespace);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        // Open input & output files
        fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        transform(fis, fos, transformer, name);
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }
}

// Teo - inefficient, but who cares
private static String parse(String option, String[] arg, String desc, boolean required) throws ParseException {
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
        if (option.equals(arg[i])) {
            if (i + 1 < arg.length) {
                String value = arg[i + 1].trim();
                return value;
            } else {
                throw new ParseException(option + " must be followed by an argument", i);
            }
        }
    }
    if (required) {
        throw new ParseException(desc + " is required", 0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
 }
}
```

This is my XSL file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                          xmlns:x="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2" 
                          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2 fixml-main-5-0-SP2_.xsd"
                          xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
                          exclude-result-prefixes="xs math">


<xsl:accumulator name="MktSegID" streamable="yes" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule match="x:Batch/x:MktDef" select="string(@MktSegID)"/>
   </xsl:accumulator>

 <xsl:mode streamable="yes" use-accumulators="MktSegID"/>
 <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

 <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
 <xsl:param name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
 <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />


 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:text>PriSetPx,TxnTm,ID,Src,EventTyp,Dt,Exch,MktSegID </xsl:text>
 <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::x:Evnt"/>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:Evnt">
<xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(../../@PriSetPx), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
<xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(../../@TxnTm), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(../@ID), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(../@Src), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />

 <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(@EventTyp), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(@Dt), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />

 <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(../@Exch), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, accumulator-before('MktSegID'), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
<xsl:value-of select="$break" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is my sample xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<FIXML xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2 fixml-main-5-0-SP2_.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2" s="2012-04-23" v="FIX.5.0SP2">
<Batch ID="RPTTA111PUBLI20170509">
    ************ This is one set of loop************
           <MktDef MktID="XEUR" MktSegID="19699" EfctvBizDt="2017-05-11" NxtEfctvBizDt="2017-05-15" MktSeg="FCEA" MarketSegmentDesc="FUT ON EUR AUD" Sym="DE000A160WW0" ParentMktSegmID="FCUR" Ccy="AUD" MktSegStat="10" USFirmFlag="Y" PartID="1">
        <Undly Exch="XREU" Sym="CEA" ID="EU0009654748" Src="4" PrevClsPx="1.47"/>
    </MktDef>

    <SecDef PriSetPx="68708.52">
        <Instrmt ID="221096" Src="M" SecTyp="FUT" Status="1" Exch="XLDX" ProdCmplx="1" CFI="FFMCSX" MatDt="2024-12-17" MMY="202412" Mult="1" ValMeth="FUT" SettlMeth="C" PxPrcsn="2" MinPxIncr="0.01" MinPxIncrAmt="0.01">
            <Evnt EventTyp="7" Dt="2024-12-17"/>
        </Instrmt>
    </SecDef>
            <SecDef>
             .
             .
             .
            </SecDef>
            <SecDef>
             .
             .
             .
            </SecDef>
            <SecDef>
             .
             .
             .
            </SecDef>
   ************ This is one set of loop************
  ############ This will continue n number of times having millions of line###########        
</Batch>
</FIXML>
```

The output should come like this as a columns with data but @Exch and @MktSegId data are missing,

```
PriSetPx TxnTm ID Src EventTyp Dt Exch MktSegID
```

Please help me to understand where I did wrong in the XSL code and How to get the column data.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, in your XML snippet that `Evnt` element has a parent element with the attribute `Exch="XLDX"` so instead of `../../@Exch` I suppose you want `../@Exch`.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the update. What about the MktSegId ? how to get that one ?

Comment: Is that the `MktSegID` attribute of the preceding `MktDef` element? Well, with normal XSLT/XPath you would navigate to that element `preceding-sibling::MktDef[1]/@MktSegID` but I notice that you use `<xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>` and XSLT 3.0, so that might not be possible to navigate.

Comment: Hi Martin, Can you please give me some example regarding "preceding-sibling::MktDef[1]/@MktSegID" with no memory consumption because I have more than1 GB data of xml file to parse.

Comment: You first need to edit your question to explain and show the structure of your input XML, currently it is not clear what makes up the size of the XML, whether there is a single `Batch` with a single `MktDef` followed by thousands of `SecDef` with `Evnt` children or whether there are thousands of `Batch` elements. So without knowing the exact repeating structure there is no way to tell whether and how to solve that task.

Comment: Hi Martin, I just updated the xml. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up an accumulator with

```
<xsl:accumulator name="MktSegID" streamable="yes" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule match="x:Batch/x:MktDef" select="string(@MktSegID)"/>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

add `<xsl:mode streamable="yes" use-accumulators="MktSegID"/>` to the `xsl:mode` and then instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(../../../@MktSegID), $quote)" />
```

use

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, accumulator-before('MktSegID'), $quote)" />
```

As already said in a comment, it appears instead of `<xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(../../@Exch), $quote)" />` you rather want `<xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(../@Exch), $quote)" />`.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have updated the xsl s you mentioned above but I am getting below error, tried in google but unable to get the idea of what the error is,
FATAL ERROR:  'Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(accumulator-before, [literal-expr(MktSegID)])'.'
           :Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(accumulator-before, [literal-expr(MktSegID)])'.
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Error checking type of the expression
'funcall(accumulator-before, [literal-expr(MktSegID)])'.

Comment: That is XSLT 3.0 code making use of streaming so you will need to use Saxon 9.8 EE and `com.saxonica.config.StreamingTransformerFactory` i.e. `Transformer transformer = new com.saxonica.config.StreamingTransformerFactory().newTransformer(stylesource);` and the provide a SaxSource or StreamSource as the input. Otherwise the whole use of streaming XSLT 3.0 is not possible.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you for your quick response. I was trying to add Saxon 9.8 EE to my client project and came to know that it is not a free software and client is not happy with this as we won't work much on this type of XML files. Could you please suggest me if any free software available to get this functionality. Thank you in Advance!

Comment: I don't know of any open-source XSLT 3.0 implementation that supports streaming. Of course SAX and XMLStreamReader are part of the Java JRE so you would need to use those APIs and a Java program written using them to create the CSV from the XML.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you very much for your quick response and your valuable solution.